# Articles on the meaning behined the lyrics of Funny How Love Is by Fine Young Cannibals

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I am looking for articles and quotes on the story behind the song "Funny how love is", by Fine Young Cannibals. Specifically, is he still in love with his ex and doesn't want to see her because it will hurt? Or did he realize this was a bad relationship and does not want anything to do with her anymore? Or is it open to our interpretation?

Though I am mainly looking for referenced materials on the specific question, I would love to hear some users' interpretations of the whole song (not sure if it is acceptable on this SE, and if not, kindly comment and I will edit the Q).

Answer (score 0):

She left him. Just the sight of her belongings hurt him. She now wants to be platonic friends with him, calling him and sending him letters. He doesnt want to be friends, doesnt want to be contacted. He can't believe what happened to their relationship, and how she can just move on without him.